# Scala IDE plugin won't compile Scala code after conversion to Maven project and back

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven, scala-ide

I am using the older Eclipse plug-in (not the standalone) 3.0.0.v-2_09 with Scala 2.9.3.  I converted a project to Maven and then removed Maven nature.  Now, when I clean / build the project, none of the Scala classes show up in the bin folder, but the Java classes do.  Needless to say, this messes up imports in the Java classes and I can't run it.  What's happening and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to Add Scala Nature back?

Comment: it has scala nature, and the scala library on the build path